# Android Studio не появляется ActionBar

Tags: java, android, actionbar

Создаю проект в Android Studio - `Blank Activity`.  По умолчанию активити наследуется от `ActionBarActivity` и `ActionBar` есть, если наследуюсь от `Activity` или `FragmentActivity`, тогда `ActionBar` нет.

В чем проблема? В Eclipse такого не было.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если будете использовать тему не `AppCompat`,а какую-нибудь `Holo`, то будет вам экшенбар, если наследоваться от `Activity` или даже `FragmentActivity` .
Просто ADT для Eclipse видимо не обновлялся уже давно и про наимоднейший Material Design знать не знает.

PS: Надо сказать, что в наше время `ActionBarActivity` безнадежно устарел, вместо него модно использовать `AppCompatActivity`, о чем IDE должна была вам непременно сообщить.